# How to fetch only related data?

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js

Assuming a simple one-to-many relationship, e.g.

```
const Blog = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'blog',
  posts: function () {
    return this.hasMany(Post);
  }
});

const Post = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'post',
  blog: function () {
    return this.belongsTo(Blog)
  }
});
```

How do I fetch all posts of a specific blog entry without fetching the blog entry?

Using:

```
Blog
  .where('id', args.id)
  .fetch({
    withRelated: [
      Post
    ]
  })
  .call('related', 'post')
  .call('toJSON');
```

causes an extranous request.

The only way I have found to do it is by querying `Post` object using a custom query, e.g.

```
Post
  .where('blog_id', parent.id)
  .fetchAll()
  .call('toJSON');
```

The problem with the latter approach is that it negates the purpose of having the relations set in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiate a model (you can use `new Model` or [`Model.forge()`](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-static-forge)) and set the primary key (however you want, but passing it in initial attributes is usually easiest). Then call [`model.load()`](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-instance-load) to eager load the related models. Example:

```js
Blog
  .forge({
    id: 1
  })
  .load('posts')
  .call('related', 'posts')
  .call('toJSON')
  .then((posts) => {
    console.log('posts', posts);
  });
```